# Performance problems when sending small files through Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am building a web server application that sends files of varying size from a server to a client upon request using the HTTP 1.1 protocol and chunked Transfer-Encoding.

I am using Java `Sockets`/`ServerSockets` to handle the connections. I am sending data to the client using the output stream obtained from `socket.getOutputStream()`. Note: I am *not* wrapping the socket's output stream in a `BufferedOutputStream`.

(I am using chrome debugger to analyze resource timings)

The problem that I am seeing is that a file of size 1285 bytes (plus headers and chunk encoding) takes well over 50ms for chrome to receive its first byte for the request. (Chrome reports a TTFB of ~50ms), followed by a quick remainder of the transfer (1-2ms) **(total transfer time ~52ms)**

But if I increase the size of the file to 1286 bytes, the TTFB dramatically decreases down to ~1ms. **(total transfer time ~3ms)**

I have tried force `flush`ing the `OutputStream` at varying points along the way, including after the request headers, after chunks, and even attempting multiple `flush` calls at each point just for fun.

**My question:** Why is the transfer time so much longer for a small file as compared to any file above or equal to 1286 bytes? And what can I do to fix this performance issue?

**My theory:** Something in the underlying socket implementation is ignoring the Java request to `flush` the underlying socket's buffer, in spite of the Java calls to `flush()`.

Comment: it could be because you are always testing the small file first and large file later, and it might be attempting to establish the connection, can you try it other way round (sending the large one first and small one later) and see if you are getting the same results?

Comment: I just updated the question to clarify that this is a web server-type application, and so the files are requested at separate times. The chrome debugger splits out the connection overhead into a separate portion of the graph, so the wait time I'm seeing is not including any connection overhead for either file.

Comment: I suggest adding a `BufferedOutputStream`, and removing all the flushes except the last, and that the important metric isn't the time to the first byte but the time to the last one.

Comment: I updated the question to show the "total tranfser time" in each scenario. Unfortunately, adding a `BufferedOutputStream` into the mix only adds additional delay to the responses. Because in that case, I have both native socket buffering, as well as java stream buffering.

Comment: What you're seeing is the effect of the Nagle algorithm. Try turning it off, but *with* the `BufferedOutputStream.`

Comment: Since @EJP has already responded with disabling Nagle's algo, I am deleting my answer that has the same suggestion.

Comment: As the code stands, there is only one `flush`. The other stuff was just for testing. Will give turning on `TCP_NODELAY` a shot.

Comment: Thanks! Turning on `TCP_NODELAY` solved The problem. But using a `BufferedOuptutStream` instead of an `OutputStream` has no effect on transfer time in my testing so far.

Comment: @Khanna111 could you repost your answer? Your solution was the simplest and most accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Nagle's algorithm would resolve this issue.

http://www.boundary.com/blog/2012/05/know-a-delay-nagles-algorithm-and-you/